When uploading files to Google Drive I can't put the file title
The file is uploaded to my drive but Untitled
fn uploadFile(token: String, path: String, name: String, mimeType: String) {
    let mut headers = header::HeaderMap::new();

    headers.insert("Authorization",format!("Bearer {token}").parse().unwrap());
    headers.insert("Content-Type", format!("{mimeType}").parse().unwrap());

    let form = multipart::Form::new()
        .text("name", name)
        .file("file", format!("{path}")).unwrap();

    let client = reqwest::blocking::Client::new();

    let res = client.post("https://www.googleapis.com/upload/drive/v3/files?uploadType=multipart")
        .headers(headers)
        .multipart(form)
        .send().unwrap()
        .text().unwrap();

    println!("{}", res);
}

The file is uploaded to my drive but Untitled
{
    "kind": "drive#file",
    "id": "1Zo5_lPcI7k02p4PQVI31aaroU1-mq4J_",
    "name": "Untitled",
    "mimeType": "application/pdf"
}

This works
curl -X POST -L https://www.googleapis.com/upload/drive/v3/files?uploadType=multipart \
     -H "Authorization: Bearer " \
     -F "metadata={name : ''};type=application/json;charset=UTF-8" \
     -F "file=@;type="


I think the problem is this part:
let form = multipart::Form::new()
           .text("name", name)
           .file("file", format!("{path}")).unwrap();

In this case .text("name", name) is probably transmitted as URL-encoded form data (application/x-www-form-urlencoded), not transmitted as JSON (application/json) which is what the Google Drive API expects.
Maybe try to instead create a multipart::Part manually, so that you can specify the mime type, and add that to the form:
/* this is just an example to show what the function expects, but you
can use serde_json with the json! macro or any other way to serialise the
name into a JSON string */
let json_string = "{\"name\": \"Another name\"}";
let form = multipart::Form::new()
           .part("json", multipart::Part::text(json_string).mime_str("application/json").unwrap())
           .file("file", format!("{path}")).unwrap();


Thanks dreamlax for your contribution, the file is still uploaded
untitled.

This was the solution:
fn upload_file(token: &str, path: &str, name: &str, mime_type: &str) {
    let mut headers = header::HeaderMap::new();
    headers.insert("Authorization", format!("Bearer {token}").parse().unwrap());
    let mut map = Map::new();
    map.insert("name".to_string(), name.into());
    let json_string = serde_json::to_string(&map).unwrap();
    let form = multipart::Form::new()
        .part(
            "file",
            multipart::Part::text(json_string)
                .mime_str("application/json")
                .unwrap(),
        )
        .part(
            "file",
            multipart::Part::file(format!("{path}"))
                .unwrap()
                .mime_str(mime_type)
                .unwrap(),
        );
    let client = reqwest::blocking::Client::new();
    let res = client
        .post("https://www.googleapis.com/upload/drive/v3/files?uploadType=multipart")
        .headers(headers)
        .multipart(form)
        .send()
        .unwrap()
        .text()
        .unwrap();
    println!("{}", res);
}

Dreamlax it put me on the right path. The problem was in the parts of the file. One of the application/json type and the other of the type of file that is uploaded.
